# How can I use the Pivot Point properly? Or is this something else that I am not aware of?

Tags: modeling, animation, node-editor, geometry-nodes, objects

I am a beginner with Blender, and this is something I cannot avoid the same mistakes with my other projects.

**1. What happens with my screenshot (see below) when I select the icing topping for the donut? Can you see that it has multiple circles?**

I noticed that the pivot is messed up when I add or remove items. I wouldn't say I liked the idea when I try to delete one item, and it constantly deletes more than one item whose pivot is all connected. I want to know how to separate the pivots from one another.

I couldn't figure out if it was my fault for setting up the shape in the beginning. I need some good advice to avoid making the same mistake.

**2. How can I select the items without seeing pivot circles or whatever it is called with the outline?**

I asked because it prevents me from being able to select other items or proceed to the next step without those messing layouts.

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the title and by *"... when I try to delete one item, and it constantly deletes more than one item whose pivot is all connected."*. There is the [Pivot Point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/index.html) in Blender that is used for transformations like rotation or scaling. Imagine a small solar system. If you rotate the earth with the pivot point set to the center of the earth, it will rotate around itself. If you move the pivot point to the sun, the earth will rotate around the sun.

Comment: I can't tell what these circle lines are. I guess it's because you have not only sprinkles in your *Sprinkles* collection but also a camera, an Empty, and 2 other collections. You can see it in the outliner (right top). All objects in this collection will be copied multiple times because the sprinkles are created from this collection (=instances are created). Remove everything except the sprinkles from the collection and check if this fixes the circle problem.